# SVN Commit error: Can't open file txn-current-lock Permission denied

Tags: tortoisesvn, commit, permission-denied

I can do checkouts, update and such. But when I try to commit changes, SVN gives me the following error:

> Can't open file '/svn/p/pokemonium/code/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied

I am using Windows 7 x64 SP1 with latest version of TortoiseSVN.
UAC is off, my account has read and write access, etc.

I can commit fine to other svn repositorys.

Comment: Questions about Pokemon are strictly forbidden. ;)  Did you try to do a clean up?

Comment: have you tried with the no --no-auth-cache command line switch - maybe you've cached some invalid credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

1. Make a back up copy of your working copy (just to be safe).
2. Make another copy your entire working copy off somewhere else.
3. Take the copy and delete all of the SVN folders out of it
4. Delete your working copy and do a fresh checkout
5. now copy/paste your corrupted working copy over your fresh checkout.

### it is critical for this to work that you have completely removed ever _svn or .svn folder from your corrupted working copy before you perform the copy/paste.

This will leave you (hopefully) with a working copy that shows (!) on all the files you had modified since your last commit.  And fixes your lock issue.

Comment: That didnt fix it for me :( Also tried a new checkout, didn't work either

Comment: Accepted this as answer since it's probably best option to try.

Answer (score 12):

For me it ended up being a permissions issue on the server.  I have my repo on a linux box, and ssh in to use svnadmin.  For convenience sake, I had executed my create repository command as root.  I was looking to get source I had on my Windows box into the repo, so was using TortoiseSVN to set up trunk/branches/tags.  The directory containing the repo on the server was owned by root, and Tortoise was coming in as apache.  I chowned the directory on the server to apache:apache, and it all went smoothly.

```
chown apache:apache -R my_repo_root
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had to re-chown the repo files on the server after loading a dump, and had to do this with `chown www-data:www-data -R repos` as I don't have an `apache` user or group.

Comment: This worked for me. "chown www-data:www-data -R repository"

Comment: Worked for me too.

Comment: Yep. Permissions were the culprit. However, on Arch Linux under Apache http is the owner and group. chown http:http -R my_repo_root. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

This is a server configuration issue. On windows host Visual SVN server runs under NETWORK SERVICE account by default. I solved this problem by granting full access rights to the repository folder to this account. Another option is switching Visual SVN service to the SYSTEM account, but that could pose a potential security risk.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after I re-installed Windows 7 and just copied the SVN Repository from the old Windows to the new one.

After trying the steps that Mr. Manager proposed, the problem was still not fixed in my case.

After making sure that the permissions was setup correctly for the SVN Repository folder I just deleted the file 'txn-current-lock' in the /db folder of the project. That fixed it for me. From thereon I could commit my project again.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue on Unix box

Restarting the Apache service of the SVN server solved myproblem.

-f httpd.conf -k stop

-f httpd.conf -k start

Answer (score 0):

In my own case, my linux server had been restarted after a power loss.  The file system remained mounted as read-only since some journal repairs had been made.  Rebooting the machine restored full function.

Answer (score 0):

permissions worked for me too

error

```
repo/db/txn-current-lock: Permission denied
```

fix

```
chown apache:apache -R my_repo_root
```